# Noun to go with "optional"

Tags: single-word-requests

How do you say *optional-ness*?

I looked at a lot of synonyms of *optional* to try to find something I could turn into a noun, but nothing looked very good.

Example sentence:

> If what I wrote doesn't indicate clearly that I'm suggesting an *optional* alternative assignment, then I would invite you to help me phrase the optional-ness more clearly.

**Update**:

> If what I wrote doesn't indicate clearly that the alternative assignment I'm suggesting is **optional, and not required**, then I would invite you to help me phrase the **lack of necessity** more clearly.

Comment: Would  [optionality](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/optionality) serve your purpose?

Comment: Do you want "the fact that some particular thing is an option" or "the fact that some number of options exist"?

Comment: @JohnFeltz - The former.

Comment: Have you considered *alternate*?

Comment: @JohnFeltz _Alternate_ and _optional_ aren't really synonyms are they? Optional means that something can be taken or left, alternate means that there is a choice of what to take but one of them is necessary. For example ship and aeroplane may be alternate ways to get to a package holiday destination but the organised tours once there would be optional.

Comment: Is there a reason you want it to be one word rather than, say, a two word phrase? For example 'help me express the optional nature of the assignment more clearly/express the discretionary nature more clearly'?

Comment: @Spagirl -If there isn't a single word for this, then obviously I'll have to resort to a phrase or a rewrite, but if there is a one-word equivalent to *optional-ness*, I would like to learn it.

Comment: Electiveness? https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/electiveness

Comment: @RichardKayser - What do you think of my update?

Comment: Your update doesn't distinguish this question from the expected duplicate (it merely gives another version of the target sentence).

Comment: Are you looking for necessary is to optional (ADJ) as necessity is to X? "Dinner is necessary but dessert is optional" -> "Dinner is a necessity but dessert is X"?

Comment: @Mitch - My update is an attempt to rewrite my sentence to fit the word proposed in the duplicate.  // I don't really understand your second comment.  Basically, the answer in the duplicate advises one to flip the point of view and use "necessity" instead of an equivalent for "optional-ness," and I am hoping for feedback regarding my attempt to follow that advice.